# FlexCAN linux driver for freescalle iMX6dl

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, can-bus, nxp-microcontroller

is there an open source FlexCAN Linux driver for the iMX6dl SOM ?
if so where can i get it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already in upstream in *drivers/net/can/flexcan.c*

Kconfig excerpt:

> ```
> CAN_FLEXCAN
>   tristate "Support for Freescale FLEXCAN based chips"
>   depends on ARM || PPC
>   ---help---
>     Say Y here if you want to support for Freescale FlexCAN.
> ```